# Failed to execute goal on project AirportWeb

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

> I am facing issue at the time of maven install. Here is my parent POM file
>   AirportSys/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mavenDemo</groupId>
<artifactId>AirportSys</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>AirportRepo</module>
    <module>AirportServices</module>
    <module>AirportWeb</module>
</modules>

</project>
```

> AirportRepo/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mavenDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>AirportSys</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>AirportRepo</artifactId>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <jdk.version>1.7.0</jdk.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <!-- Mysql jars -->
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate jars -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SpringFramework jars -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles jars -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-jsp -->
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>

        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>

        <version>3.0.8</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
</project>
```

> AirportServices/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mavenDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>AirportSys</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>AirportServices</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mavenDemo</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <artifactId>AirportRepo</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

> AiportWeb/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mavenDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>AirportSys</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.mavenDemo</groupId>
<artifactId>AirportWeb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>AirportWeb Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mavenDemo</groupId>
        <artifactId>AirportServices</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>AirportWeb</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

> Here is error at the time of maven install-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for com.mavenDemo:AirportServices:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project AirportWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mavenDemo:AirportWeb:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mavenDemo:AirportServices:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ->
```

> I have already added all the dependency what is the issue in this code.

Comment: Where do you execute the `mvn install`?  at the `AirportWeb` directory?

Comment: yes at AirportWeb directory, I have done it via cmd and eclipse as well still i am facing issue. Is there any issue in my AirportServices/pom.xml file i didn't find any issue in this file.

Comment: Please try to execute at the `AirportSys` directory. Since the `AirportServices` may not be available yet.

Comment: Yes, since it is a parent for all sub modules. Maven will install it together with those sub modules and make them available on your local repository. Please visit the following for further information, https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Comment: thank you it build successfully.

Comment: @Cœur thanks for informing. I will take care for this in future.

Comment: @Cœur Thank you for informing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the error message as

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project AirportWeb: 
    Could not resolve dependencies for project 
    com.mavenDemo:AirportWeb:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
    Could not find artifact com.mavenDemo:AirportServices:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

together with the comment that show us as we're executing `mvn install` at the `AirportWeb` directory.

Then the proper location should be the parent project directory, the `AirportSys`. Since it is a parent for all sub modules. Maven will install it together with those sub modules and make them available on our local repository.

Please visit the following for further information, [Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).